# Does change in Props Data Change the state of components or will it render the change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning React js, and the differences between props and States are apparent.

But will the change in data passed in the prop cause the component to re-render or will it still be static with the data passed initially?

I still have reservations on props values changes, if it does cause a re-render of the component(not changing the data within the components)?

Comment: `But will the change in data passed in the prop cause the component to re-render`, this. Any change in state or in props wil cause a re-render. Otherwise changes to a prop's value would not be displayed (which obviously is not what you want).

Comment: The last sentence is what confuses me, are you saying the value won't change  before or after re-render?

Comment: No, what I am saying is this: If you have a prop with value `1` and you display this prop somewhere on your website, if you now change the value of the prop to `2`, your component **has to** re-render (it has to display now 2 instead of 1). Otherwise, the change in value would not be displayed on your website (which obviously would be a very bad user experience).

Comment: Got it after I reread the comment :) thanks for the clarification<3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change in props will cause a re-render.

If you do not want this you can use a state like this:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const [firstRenderProps] = useState(props);
```

firstRenderProps will always have the same value after a re-render

Comment: Thanks,  Does this mean you  build dynamic interactions with props?

Comment: Dynamic interactions aren't really related to props, but they are related to the useState hook I used in the example. You can find more info on this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate